# Create Team using powershell and non-delegated permissions

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I need to a solution that fulfills the following requirements:

- Create a new private team
- Set the alias of the team (the sharepoint site url)
- Using clientid and secret, an access token, certiifcate, or any other, **non-delegated** permission

Case: Previously we had a powershell script, that used a service account like this:

```
$credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'teamprovisioning'  
$connection = Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $credential
New-Team -DisplayName $teamname -Description $description -Owner "..." -Visibility Private -MailNickName $teamalias
```

But now legacy authentication is disabled and the credential object is not working anymore. So, we registered an app, gave the necessary permissions:

[image]

Changed the connection in the script:

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AadAccessToken $AuthenticationResult -TenantId $tenantId -AccountId $ClientId
```

But the `New-Team` command fails with the following error message:
`New-Team : The given key was not present in the dictionary.`

Search didn't give anything related. Please advise, do we need more permissions? Can we use some other method that matches the requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using MicrosoftTeams PowerShell module version 2.3.1.

Also please verify below permissions in your App registration:

[image]

```
Then run below commands:

$AuthenticationResult = '<AccessToken>'
$tenantId = '295e356b-4c71-45d8-98bf-xxxxx'
$ClientId = '45604b00-cfae-400e-961a-xxxxx'

Connect-MicrosoftTeams -MsAccessToken $AuthenticationResult -TenantId $tenantId -AccountId $ClientId

$teamname = 'PrivateTeam'
$description = 'My Private Team'
$teamalias = 'PrivateTeam44'

New-Team -DisplayName $teamname -Description $description -Visibility Private -MailNickName $teamalias
```

Please refer below docs for your future reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/connect-microsoftteams?view=teams-ps